# Scraping webpage with multiple HTMLs and bodies

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I want to click an element in a list on a website through VBA macro. However, the website is build in a way that it has another "html", "head" and "body" tags build into the ones that are on top, possibly because it loads a list of clickable items only after I choose "open items" from a dropdown.
I think this is the reason I cannot find a way to reference the button in my code, as it is sitting in the second html. For example, using `IE.Document.GetElementsByTag("html")` will display 0 even though there are more than one html tags on this page (two to be exact). The furthest I can get with my scraping is right before the second html tag in the page. Also when i try to use `Debug.Print IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0).innerText`, the code after second HTML tag is omitted there.
I am not posting any more code because the problematic part is visible only under "Inspect element" in IE, not when I view "Source" in IE. Therefore I am just hoping for more general suggestions on how to get to an element in such embedded HTML document.
Thanks, Bartek

Comment: There are no guidelines for this, because formatting an HTML document that way is not part of the specification.  It doesn't break your browser only because browsers tend to be very forgiving of bad layout.  Post the HTML for the elements you want to reach: I think you can pretty much ignore the multiple `<body>` instances.

Comment: If an HTML element is visible on the page then it should be accessible via VBA - you just need to find the correct path to reach it.  For example it might be nested inside a frame.

Comment: Hey Tim, I tried scraping the iframe but with no success. I have also created a separate question specifically for scraping the iframe with HTML posted and the code I came up with so far, if you mind a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793500/ie-automation-scrape-td-in-iframe-through-vba