# IE automation: scrape <td> in <iframe> through VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am trying to automate IE through VBA to click a button that is embedded in an  "iframe" as on screenshot below (image in the last line):

[image]

However my code is unsuccesful in referencing the button (the last line doesn't print any value):

```
Sub intercept()

Dim my_title As String
my_title = "Accounting"

marker = 0
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    page_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    page_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

    If page_title Like my_title & "*" Then 'compare to find if the desired web page is already open
        Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
        marker = 1
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

If marker = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("A matching webpage was NOT found")
Else
    MsgBox ("A matching webpage was found")
End If

Set mytable = IE.Document.frames(1).Document.tables(1)

Debug.Print mytable.getElementsByTagName("td").Length

End Sub
```

I have also tried: `IE.Document.frames(0).Document.tables(0)`.

Any help on how to click on this element is appreciated.

Comment: Try: `Set mytable = IE.Document.frames(1).ContentDocument.tables(1)`

Comment: Thanks Marc, unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: `Set mytable = IE.Document.getElementByTagName("IFRAME")(0).ContentDocument.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(0)`

Comment: I tried, but still `Debug.Print mytable.Length` or `Debug.Print mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr").Length` returns nothing.

Comment: What happens when you make use of the link connected to `iframe`, i meant the link within `src=---`. If you find the table in that link then there is a workaround otherwise it's hard to provide you with any solution without facing the real web.

Comment: Thanks Shahin, that is actually a great idea: launching this link in another tab and scraping the table there.